# Kakfa Connect Oracle Source Connector

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are trying to use Kafka connect docker to connect to Oracle database as a source connector.

We use the following image: https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/full-stack.yml

We get the following error:

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException:
    ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied\n for configuration Couldn't open connection to
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc.xyz.com\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017:
    invalid username/password; logon denied\n for configuration Couldn't open connection to
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@//abc.xyz.com\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

We have tested the Oracle connection with the same Url ,Username and Password from SQL Developer and Spring boot service it works fine.

**We are facing the ORA-01017: invalid username/password issue only with kafka connect docker image.
Please note: we are using the same connector jar ie. ojdbc8**

Any suggestions/solutions on how we can solve this issue is greatly appreciated .

Attached screenshot of the postman call for your reference.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otDbE.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include your full connector configuration please? Images are not so easy to read. If you mask host/ip details please make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

while making the POST call i was using 
"connection.username" instead of "connection.user" which led to the above error